# convert a href tag to button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code online and I want to change the text link to a button, can someone help me please. Here the original script link https://jsfiddle.net/cferdinandi/qgpxvhhb/41/
I want to convert the a href text link Toggle Div (normal speed) to a button

```js
// Get the transition timing
var getTiming = function (elem) {
    var timing = 350;
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-fast')) {
        timing = 100;
    }
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-slow')) {
        timing = 2000;
    }
    return timing;
};

// Show an element
var show = function (elem) {

    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Get the natural height of the element
    var getHeight = function () {
        elem.style.display = 'block'; // Make it visible
        var height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px'; // Get it's height
        elem.style.display = ''; //  Hide it again
        return height;
    };

    var height = getHeight(); // Get the natural height
    elem.classList.add('is-visible'); // Make the element visible
    elem.style.height = height; // Update the max-height

    // Once the transition is complete, remove the inline max-height so the content can scale responsively
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '';
    }, timing);

};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {

    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Give the element a height to change from
    elem.style.height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px';

    // Set the height back to 0
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '0';
    }, 1);

    // When the transition is complete, hide it
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }, timing);

};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem, timing) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
```

```css
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 350ms ease-in-out, opacity 750ms ease-in-out;
}

.show-fast {
    transition: height: 100ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.show-slow {
    transition: height: 2000ms ease-in-out, opacity 2500ms ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="toggle" href="#example">Toggle Div (normal speed)</a>
  
</p>




<div class="toggle-content" id="example">
    This content reveals when click on button.
</div>
```

tag in that code to a button click.

From text link:

```
Toggle Div (normal speed)
```

To a button to click on

```
Click
```

Comment: Why don't you change the HTML from an anchor to a button?

Comment: You could try to either CSS the A tag to look like a button, or wrap the A text with a Button perse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this??

```js
// Get the transition timing
var getTiming = function (elem) {
    var timing = 350;
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-fast')) {
        timing = 100;
    }
    if (elem.classList.contains('show-slow')) {
        timing = 2000;
    }
    return timing;
};

// Show an element
var show = function (elem) {

    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Get the natural height of the element
    var getHeight = function () {
        elem.style.display = 'block'; // Make it visible
        var height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px'; // Get it's height
        elem.style.display = ''; //  Hide it again
        return height;
    };

    var height = getHeight(); // Get the natural height
    elem.classList.add('is-visible'); // Make the element visible
    elem.style.height = height; // Update the max-height

    // Once the transition is complete, remove the inline max-height so the content can scale responsively
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '';
    }, timing);

};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {

    // Get the transition timing
    var timing = getTiming(elem);

    // Give the element a height to change from
    elem.style.height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px';

    // Set the height back to 0
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.height = '0';
    }, 1);

    // When the transition is complete, hide it
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }, timing);

};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem, timing) {

    // If the element is visible, hide it
    if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
        hide(elem);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, show it
    show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

    // Prevent default link behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the content
    var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
    if (!content) return;

    // Toggle the content
    toggle(content);

}, false);
```

```css
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 350ms ease-in-out, opacity 750ms ease-in-out;
}

.show-fast {
    transition: height: 100ms ease-in-out, opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.show-slow {
    transition: height: 2000ms ease-in-out, opacity 2500ms ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-content.is-visible {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

.mybutton { padding:10px;
    border:0px;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:green;
    
    }
    
.mybutton > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;}
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="mybutton">
    <a class="toggle" href="#example">Toggle Div (normal speed)</a>
  </button>
  
</p>




<div class="toggle-content" id="example">
    This content reveals when click on button.
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: cool, I'm glad it worked for you please accept the answer so this case is closed thanks

Comment: Im new on stackovever. How to accept the answer and close this question?

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks